# SSH: Difference between "Permission Denied(publickey,keyboard-interactive)" and "Too many authentication failures"

Tags: ssh

I am confused about different errors thrown from different MAC laptops, while logging in via ssh.

I am intentionally giving wrong password(for some testing reasons) for each machine and getting different errors:

In one case:

```
Warning: Permanently added '10.209.*.*' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
Password:
Password:
a123@10.209.*.*: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

In this case, OPEN ssh on target server is **openSSH_6.9p1**

In ssh to other machine:

```
Warning: Permanently added '172.21.*.*' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
Password:
Password:
a123@172.21.*.*'s password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
a123@172.21.*.*'s password: 
Received disconnect from 172.21.*.* port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
```

In this case, openssh version on target server is **OpenSSH_7.6p1**.

I checked sshd_config file on both machines and both are identical.

What causes these 2 different errors. Is it based on ssh version or anything else?

Comment: (Increase the log verbosity on the ssh server and) check what error is triggered on the server, rather than interpreting the symptom only from the client.

Comment: I tried to search for increasing verbose level for MAC, but could not find any informative link except: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382825/where-to-find-sshd-logs-on-macos-sierra.  But it did not help much. And it seems that we can not have much info about ssh server in mac. However in both cases I get following error in logs: _Service exited with abnormal code: 255_